# Programming musical frequencies *not a strictly physics question*

Tags: frequency, software

I might be barking up the wrong tree, as I have no idea which site my question is most appropriate for. Let me know if I should try somewhere else. (I am a mathematician, I have not used the physics site, so I am sorry if I am not conforming to norms). I figured the physics community would have the best ideas, given that you work with frequency the most.

I am generating numbers using $y = |10^3 \cdot sin(\frac{1}{x})|$ in some interval near 0. Doing this, you end up with numbers all over the place, but I want to call them musical frequencies. What I want to do is play these frequencies sequentially.  I basically want to demonstrate the erratic oscillation of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ as x goes to 0 through audio. Is there a program or way about this anyone can suggest? Or even, a program that will play a set of inputted frequencies? I couldn't find an easy way to go about this with Java or Mathematica.

Comment: Mathematica's "Play" function wouldn't work for you?. If not, I know that LabVIEW has some tools for this

Comment: Why not just play your function as a sound wave? It will have a decreasing frequency (or increasing, if you go toward 0). There’s nothing “erratic” about the oscillation. It just gets slower or faster.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I made a HTML/JS for you to play around.
It plays the function as a frequency of a sine wave and displays the frequency on a graph in  a box.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<p id="p1"> FREQ_OUT </p>
<script>

    function sleep(ms){
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    async function play_stuff(){
        const context = new AudioContext()
        const oscillator = context.createOscillator() 
        oscillator.type = 'sine'
        oscillator.connect(context.destination)
        oscillator.start(context.currentTime)
        oldfreq=0;
        olds=0
        for(s=0;s<1000;s+=1){
            x=(s-1000)/1000;



            var freq = Math.abs(Math.sin(1.0/x))*880
            oscillator.frequency.value = freq;
            show_graph(olds/2,oldfreq/5,s/2,freq/5)
            olds = s;
            oldfreq=freq;

            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = freq;
            await sleep(50);
        }
        oscillator.stop(context.currentTime)
    }

    function show_graph(x1,y1,x2,y2){
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x1, 200-y1);
        ctx.lineTo(x2, 200-y2);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

</script>

<b>PRESS THIS TO PLAY:</b>
<input type=button onClick="play_stuff()" value="Play wavy">
```

Try it at

https://js.do/code/368683